# How to detect dismissal of the google "choose account" dialog

Tags: android, google-sso

I'm integrating Google SSO in my Android app.
I would like to know when a user was prompted with the choose account dialog and decided to click on the background, so the dialog was dismissed.

The choose account dialog is triggers by:

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        Activity activity = MyActivity.getActivity();
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_TOKEN);    
    }
```

I'm using onActivityResult, but I don't know how to distinct a failure in login and a dismissal of the dialog.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_GET_TOKEN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //do something
        } else {
            // This is where I get when sign in fails, or when user dismisses the dialog
        }
    }
}
```

Help is much appreciated,
Thanks,
Giora.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog launching code:

```
 Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                new String[] {"com.google", "com.google.android.legacyimap"},
                false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_GET_TOKEN);
```

On activity result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_GET_TOKEN) {
        //result code contains 0 if dialog dismissed by clicking on background or pressing Cancel button 
        // or  -1 if OK button is clicked.Tested on Samsung galaxy S5 Android 6.0

        boolean dialogIsDismissed;
        if(resultCode ==0) dialogIsDismissed = true;
        if(resultCode ==-1) dialogIsDismissed = false;

        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //do something
        } else {
            // This is where I get when sign in fails, or when user dismisses the dialog
        }
    }
}
```

Is it what you need or I get you wrong?

Comment: The choose account dialog is popped automatically by getSignInIntent and resultCode is 0 on both cases. dismissal or not..